# How to show edges with different color along with faces in different color (android)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have drawn a cube with triangle strip and colored it. This cube is triangle_strip of 16 vertices. But now I've to show it's edges with white color. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve it.
Following code snipest shows you I drawn a cube.

```
    vertices.put(x).put(y).put(z); //1
    vertices.put(x).put(y).put(z);//2
    ........

    vertices.put(x).put(y).put(zz);//16
     gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);

    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.1f, 1.0f, -0.1f); // Rotate 

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll have to do is draw the cube, and then draw the edges of the cube again in `GL_LINES` mode.

To avoid issues with the depth buffer, you can use [glPolygonOffset](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml) to give the lines a slight bias so they show up in front of the cube.

Comment: Thanks for q reply.I'm learning and new to opengl, could please provide me tutorial,example to links to implement this.